# KendoDropDownList Not Rendering in External View

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI Core dropdown list that will not render. If I the place the kendodropdownlist in the `index.html` file it works. Also if I place it in a local `div` (still in `index.html`) with `data-role="view"` it works. But, if I place it in another HTML file that I am using as a view, it will not render as a `kendodropdownlist`. The Kendo JS is not available for that file. The index file is using `<script src="js/kendo.ui.core.min.js"></script>` . In reading the Kendo UI documentation, once I initialize the CSS and JS in the `index.html` file, it does not need to be called out again in any views. So the JS file is only called in the `index.html` file. Why am I not able to render the `KendoDropdownList` in `views/drowndownview.html`? I created a github with all the files working if anyone wants to run it and see more info. https://github.com/jacquelineflemming/kendodropdownlist

File structure

```
index.html
views/
  drowndownview.html
```

Inside the `index.html` I have a `select` in a local `div` that has the `data-role="view"` and
also in the initial view. Both `select`s here work and render as expected:

```
<div id="welcome" data-role="view" data-layout="default" data-title="Welcome" class="buttonAppearance">
    <h1>DropDownList Demo</h1>
    <p>
    Kendo Drop Down List View Demo
    </p>

    <br />
    <br />
  <select id="sizes" class=".k-dropdown" >
    <option>S - 6 3/4"</option>
    <option>M - 7 1/4"</option>
    <option>L - 7 1/8"</option>
    <option>XL - 7 5/8"</option>
  </select>

  <p>
    <a href="#list" class="" id="dropdownreflocal" data-role="button" >KendoDropDown Localview</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="views/dropdownview.html" class="" id="dropdownref" data-role="button" >KendoDropDown View</a>
  <p>
</div>

<div id="list" data-role="view" data-layout="default">
  <select id="churchselect" class=".k-dropdown" >
    <option>S - 6 3/4"</option>
    <option>M - 7 1/4"</option>
    <option>L - 7 1/8"</option>
    <option>XL - 7 5/8"</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/kendo.ui.core.min.js"></script>

<script>
  // Add a default transition for all views, to get a native
  // feel
  var app = new kendo.mobile.Application( $(document.body),{
    transition:'slide'
  });

  $('#sizes').kendoDropDownList();
  $('#churchselect').kendoDropDownList();

</script>
```

In the file `views/dropdownview.html` I have a similar `select` with a different `id`. I actually
have 3 different versions, but for brevity I'll only paste one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Drop Down List View</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="dropdownview" data-role="view" data-layout="default" data-title="Drop Down List">

        <div class="container" >
          <div class="appname" >
            <h1>Drop Down List</h1>
          </div>

          <form action="#" id="form-dropdownview">
              <!-- deleting lines -->
              <select id="churchselect" class=".k-dropdown" >
                <option>S - 6 3/4"</option>
                <option>M - 7 1/4"</option>
                <option>L - 7 1/8"</option>
                <option>XL - 7 5/8"</option>
              </select>

              <!-- deleting lines -->
          </form>
      <script>

        $("#churchselect").kendoDropDownList();


      </script>
 </div>
 </body>
```

---

Update 11/7/2014:

I updated `select` with attribute `data-role="dropdownlist"` as pointed out in comments, and it does work. But I'm unable to use `kendoDropDownList()` to set the `dataSource` or anything else.

Comment: Not really sure about a fix, but have you thought about ditching the $("#selector").kendo... and switching to the declarative method ?  Adding a data-role="dropdownlist" to your select ?

Comment: @RobinGiltner, that works! I was following the Kendo examples and docs and they have a lot of JavaScript examples. I didn't see the data-role="dropdownlist" listed. I just wonder once I expand and need to use the Kendo JS for added functionality if I'll run into issues again.